# Unable to import test accounts on paypal developer site

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am facing the issue of import old test accounts, when I try to import data with my old paypal developer account, it gives me error of invalid email id. I am sure that the email id and the password are the correct and which was working with old developer account. Please note, I am also unable to create new sandbox test account with create account option. I am a non US developer.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Paypal support issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your cookies and cache before navigating to the developer.paypal.com page and logging in.  Also try using Firefox or Chrome if you are currently using Internet Explorer, as there have been less issues with these two browsers.  Once you have cleared your cookies and cache, then try logging in and creating new accounts or importing your old ones.

Comment: I tried this method before but not worked, this time it worked in firefox. I don't know why it was not working before. I get succeed to import my old data, but still I am having issue on creating new test account. I dont know what to write in Email field, when I write something like old method, fname._xxxxxxxxxx_per@gmail.com it gives me error of invalid email id. when I enter something like test.test@gmail.com it gives available message, but how can I use the real email on sandbox test account, or will it be safe to use the email id like real email id?

Comment: You can use your real email address if you want to, its not going to send any real emails out, only emails to your developer inbox.  However also using email address in the format of fname_xxxxx_per@gmail.com should work as well.  I just tested this where I created one with xxxx_US_Biz@xxxx.com

Comment: fname_xxxxx_per@gmail.com and xxxx_US_Biz@xxxx.com both worked for me. Thanks.!